# Let $C\gt0$, I want to show that, $f(x)\leq C\|x\|,\quad \forall x\in X$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space over $\Bbb R$ and let $f: X\to \Bbb R$

Where $f$ is sublinear and when $x_n\to x,\lim\displaystyle\inf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)\geq f(x)$

Let $C\gt0$, I want to show that, $f(x)\leq C\|x\|,\quad \forall x\in X$.

Can I have a hint?

---

So $f$ doesn't satisfy absolute homogeneity or the property of coincidence, so it isn't a norm. Should my first thought be to choose a norm for my space? I haven't had to do this before, usually a space has a 'standard' norm.

Comment: what is the connection between $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ and $f$ ?

Comment: @Svetoslav Edited sorry, I thought that gave weak convergence, but perhaps more

Comment: @Svetoslav Does being a Banach space over $\Bbb R$ mean the Euclidean norm implicitly?

Comment: No, the Euclidean norm may have nothing to do with the norm in the Banach space.

Comment: What is the function $p$?

Comment: @dafinguzman Sorry was meant to be $f(x)$